# Is there a way to hook up AWS IAM with an LDAP server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, amazon-iam

The idea is to allow access to all employees within my organization with access to AWS without having to create them again in IAM.

Comment: is this what you are after? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/STSMgmtConsole-SAML.html

Comment: @DaveBennett I saw that Article when I googled; but that Article is about federating Identities using standard federation like SAML federation. I was hoping there would be something in IAM that would hook directly into LDAP APIs.

Comment: so, AWS reaches across the Internet and binds your users to your directory server via LDAP? I would doubt that AWS would support such a setup. SAML was basically invented to solve the problem you are presenting.  You assert your users' identities to be valid and present a SAML assertion to AWS. They trust it and your people are good to go. Then you can role the same infrastructure for all of your cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

This related to AWS Access and IDentity Management
The following are good resources:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_federated-users.html
https://jumpcloud.com/blog/aws-auth-ldap-and-iam/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/simple_ad_how_to.html

Also see:
https://jumpcloud.com/blog/aws-ldap-integration